# How can I paginate a lot of nested has_many association records in rails_admin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, rails-admin

That's how my edit page looks like now [image: example]

Can I paginate nested data on the edit page?

Or maybe is there a way to move options to a new section with their own CRUD and pagination (e.g. `/categories/1/options`)? If that's possible, then how?

Comment: Yes, second option (move options to a new section with their own CRUD and pagination) will be better

Comment: I agree with @evgeniy_trebin so many records means you probably need to set the association from the other side.